# Non-HTTP connections time out

Tags: connection-issues, internet, samsung-galaxy-player

I have a Samsung Galaxy Player 5. Before, I could use everything (Facebook, etc) normally. I'm not sure if I changed anything, but now the browser (Internet) loads everything fine, but Facebook &co. are unable to make a connection (timing out, as far as I understand it)

I'm not sure what I could of changed. This happens on numerous networks, so it's not a router-side thing.

What should I investigate or check?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Facebook app and others like it still use HTTP to do their work. Can you access the Facebook website through the browser?

Comment: Also, please don't guess: "(timing out, as far as I understand it)". Tell us *exactly* what you *see* the phone do.

Comment: @DanHulme: Yes, I can. I see the player 'load' for a long time (5-10 times longer than to just display a page normally) and then display 'There was an error connecting to Facebook' or similar, depending on the app.